# Using TinyMCE with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tinymce

I have TinyMCE working great in my ASP.NET MVC app except for the spellchecker. I followed this article but when I try to use the spellchecker it gives me an "Error: No Response" message.

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: We need some code to see what's going on.

Comment: What article did you follow? I'm having a hard time enabling the spellchecker as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone else was having (what sounds like) the same problem [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122659/tinymce-spellchecker-in-asp-net-mvc). The solution was to make sure the app [wasn't interpreting the spellechecker service as an attempted MVC route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122659/tinymce-spellchecker-in-asp-net-mvc/1122766#1122766). In other words, it's necessary to add something like this to your route definitions:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("TinyMCE.ashx");
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a problem with the ajax.