# TinyMCE Spellchecker in ASP .NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, tinymce, spell-checking

I followed the tutorial described [here](http://ondotnet.deap.nu/2009/01/implementing-tinymce-spellchecker-with.html), in order to make the TinyMCE Spellchecker work on a Webforms application. But I tried to do the very same thing on a MVC project and keep getting errors every time I try to use the spellchecker.

I'd like to know what changes or adjustments I need to make in order to make this word on an ASP .NET MVC project.

The error I'm getting is the following:

```
[HttpException]: The controller for path '/TinyMCE.ashx' could not be found or it does not implement
 IController.
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(Type controllerType)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String
 controllerName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute
()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well its a bit hard to know what the problem is without knowing what the error you're getting is, but I'm guessing that its because you need to ignore the route to the spell checker in your MVC. Do this by adding something like this to your MVC route definitions:

```
//ignore just the TinyMCE spell checker service:
routes.IgnoreRoute("TinyMCE.ashx");
//or if you want to be more general & ignore all ashx's:
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.ashx{*pathInfo}");
```

Without the above it would be interpreting the spellcheck request url (`TinyMCE.ashx...`) as an MVC route & try to find a matching Controller (& obviously fail).

If that's not the issue, I'd suggest posting some more info about the specific error you're seeing.

Comment: I'm sorry but it only says Error: on an alert javascript message.

Comment: If you install something like Firebug for Firefox or Fiddler, you should be able to see the actual ajax error coming back from the server.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't actually test the rule... Should be enough just to ignore using `routes.IgnoreRoute("TinyMCE.ashx");` (if that doesn't work, try the second option I gave).

Comment: @Raul Roa: You made it work? Please say what changes you made so others may benefit who have the same issues. Thanks for being a good member of the ecosystem. :)

Comment: In the referenced article I had to set the spellchecker_rpc_url setting to have a leading slash for it to work w/asp.net mvc.

spellchecker_rpc_url : "/TinyMCE.ashx?module=SpellChecker"

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty new to MVC (a little over a year) and was pretty interested in spell check for a specific page in my solution.  The above options may work for some folks, but didn't work for me (I'm not very patient, and in all honesty didn't want to ignore any routes, or modify my the system.web section of my config for something that only 5% of my solution consumers are going to use, so I didn't spend a whole lot of time on those options).

So:

1. I copied the Moxiecode.TinyMCE.dll file to a directory in my project so future contributors will    have the dll without having to search google.
2. I added a reference to the above dll to my project.
3. I created a new controller called SpellCheckController.cs that contains the following:

   ```
   public void CheckSpelling()
   {
       SpellCheckerModule spellChecker = new SpellCheckerModule();
       spellChecker.ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext.Current);
   }
   ```

(don't forget the using Moxiecode.TinyMCE.SpellChecker;)

and just referenced the controller like this in the setup options for TinyMCE in my view:

```
spellchecker_rpc_url: "@Url.Action("CheckSpelling","SpellCheck")/?module=SpellChecker"
```

I haven't ignored any routes.  I haven't added another httphandler to the what I am assuming is a pretty long list of handlers for .net, and spell check works for me now.

I also have the ability to go with something different without changing too much (assuming I figure out what TinyMCE's spellchecker is doing with the http context.

P.S.
Stack Overflow's rich text editor doesn't seem to have a spell check feature, so there are no guaranties on the above spelling :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for your post! Please do not use signatures/taglines in your posts. Your user box counts as your signature, and you can use your profile to post any information about yourself you like. [FAQ on signatures/taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures). And your spelling here was fine, btw! ;)

Comment: This work for me as i was using tinymce with knockoutjs and sammyjs